# Android Button with Left and Right Margin

Tags: android, layout

I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_in"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_green"
    android:text="@string/signin_via_email"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:typeface="sans" />
```

Now the button i dont really want to fit the whole width rather i want a margin of 10dp from the left and 10dp from the right. I have set the padding and layout_marginLeft and right attributes but they dont work. Any help ?

Kind Regards

Comment: can you post your ButtonText style code ?

Comment: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and specify the margins accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

```
 <Button
 style="@style/ButtonText"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:id="@+id/btnOk"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="OK" />
```

Comment: If you use "android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp" it also works. Note that layout_marginHorizontal only works for API 26 or higher!

Comment: use `layout_marginStart` and `layout_marginEnd`.

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

to

```
input.xml
```

..and it worked!

(I using SoftKeyboard source code and also have the same problem)

Comment: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Hello User,

Please don't use "fill_parent" on Height ever.  Please Give Actual image Height and Weight and Then Put MarginLeft and Right . It will work surely .

Comment: but can i calculate the width of the screen. I just want a margin of 10 dp on left and right of the screen. This should work  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout it will add margin to your button if Button is your root element then there is no way to add margin from that layout while adding button to some other layout you can specify margin/padding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_in"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_green"
    android:text="@string/signin_via_email"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>
```